# ESLint Expects Expressions at Random Places in Code

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

ESLint is yelling at me for this Prop definition in a Vue single-file component written in Typescript:

```js
@Prop({
    default: () => ""
}) Query!: string
```

> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>   error: Parsing error: Expression expected at ›here‹ 2:4:
>
> ```js
> @Prop({
>     default: () => ""
>     ^
> }) Query!: string
> ```

It also complains here:

```js
get RemainingTime() {
    if(!this.myData.objectProperty) return null
    return some_data
}
```

> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>   error: Parsing error: Expression expected at src/views/list/ProjectBox.vue:79:8:
>
> ```js
> get RemainingTime() {
>     if(!this.myData.objectProperty) return null
>     ^
> ```

In my eslint.rc:

```
parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
}
```

What expression is expected here -- or what else causes the linter error?

I’m happy to provide further information, but since I’m unfamiliar with the technology stack I don’t know what to include—and I don’t want to dump each configuration file here. The project was setup using vue-cli.